# How to implement a class with multiple elements already created?

Tags: python, class, implementation

I'm trying to implement a class with this structure:

```
class type_of_thing():
    def __init__(self, type, code, version, description, year, family):
        self.type = type
        self.code = code
        self.version = version
        self.description = description
        self.year = year
        self.family = family

# with this I would create a new element of this class:

obj_type1 = type_of_thing(type = "x", code = "WRT-001", version= "1-10", description= "custom", year = "2016", family = "class1")
obj_type1_2 = type_of_thing(type = "x", code = "WRT-001", version= "1-11", description= "custom", year = "2016", family = "class1")
obj_type2 = type_of_thing(type = "xy", code = "WRT-001", version= "1-12", description= "custom", year = "2016", family = "class1")
```

but I have to create a hundreds of this elements, I already have them in a list like this:

```
type of thing1:

type = "x", 
code = "WRT-001", 
version= "1-10", 
description= "custom", 
year = "2016", 
family = "class1"

type = "x", 
code = "WRT-001", 
version= "1-11", 
description= "custom", 
year = "2016", 
family = "class1"

type of thing2:

type = "xy", 
code = "WRT-001", 
version= "1-12", 
description= "custom", 
year = "2016", 
family = "class1"

type = "xy", 
code = "WRT-001", 
version= "1-10", 
description= "custom", 
year = "2016", 
family = "class1"

type of thing3:
...
...
...
```

Lets say that I could put them in lists like this:

```
type_of_thing1 = ["x","WRT-001","1-10","custom","2016","class1"]
type_of_thing1_2 = ["x","WRT-001","1-11","custom","2016","class1"]
type_of_thing2 = ["xy","WRT-001","1-12","custom","2016","class1"]
type_of_thing3 = ["...","...","...","...","..","..."]
```

So I'm trying to find a pythonic way to implement this using a class and avoid to create a bunch of objects or a bunch of lists to store all the combinations of type of things that I have.

Would it be better to manage it like a list, and access to its elements by position instead of creating a class?
What do you think that I could do something else to improve my code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include to exactly contents of at least part the list you already have because that will be needed to provide a concrete answer.

Comment: better use list or dictionary - it helps to work with this.

Comment: @furas  I was thinking in use a class because if in the future I need to add a new element I would only have to call the class object and place the needed arguments.

Comment: sorry, I was thinging about keeping objects on list `obj_type.append( type_of_thing(...) )`. The same with data before you create objects `type_of_thing = [ ["x", ...], ["x", ...], ]` and then you can use `for` loop to create lists with objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming those lists are a text string, you can just parse that list and put into a `dict`. Here is an example:

```
txt='''\
type = "x", 
code = "WRT-001", 
version= "1-10", 
description= "custom", 
year = "2016", 
family = "class1"

type = "x", 
code = "WRT-001", 
version= "1-11", 
description= "custom", 
year = "2016", 
family = "class1"'''

for block in txt.split('\n\n'): 
    di={}
    for line in block.splitlines():
        k,v=[e.strip().strip('"') for e in line.rstrip().rstrip(',').split('=')]
        di[k]=v
    print(di)
```

Prints:

```
{'type': 'x', 'code': 'WRT-001', 'version': '1-10', 'description': 'custom', 'year': '2016', 'family': 'class1'}
{'type': 'x', 'code': 'WRT-001', 'version': '1-11', 'description': 'custom', 'year': '2016', 'family': 'class1'}
```

Then call you class constructor with the dict di.

---

Based on your edit, you can do:

```
>>> keys=['type', 'code', 'version', 'description', 'year', 'family']   
>>> vals=["x","WRT-001","1-10","custom","2016","class1"]
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, vals)}
{'type': 'x', 'code': 'WRT-001', 'version': '1-10', 'description': 'custom', 'year': '2016', 'family': 'class1'}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I think that because of the answers that I got, is not a good idea to have a class and the best I can do is to have a dictionary or a list.

Answer (score -1):

Python stores it's global variables in `globals()`, you also spoke of a list of information, you can iterate through that list adding classes to `globals()`.

```
list_of_things = [("x","WRT-001","1-10","custom","2016","class1"),
                  ("x","WRT-001","1-11","custom","2016","class1"),
                  ("xy","WRT-001","1-12","custom","2016","class1")]

class type_of_thing():
    def __init__(self, type, code, version, description, year, family):
        self.type = type
        self.code = code
        self.version = version
        self.description = description
        self.year = year
        self.family = family

for i,thing in enumerate(list_of_things):
    globals()["thing_"+str(i)] = type_of_thing(thing[0],thing[1],thing[2],thing[3],thing[4],thing[5])

print(thing_0)
```

This code will create variables name `thing_0` to `thing-<Number of list indicies>`, then print the first one, `thing_0`.

Hope this helps! If it isn't what you were looking for, please tell me.

Additionally It isn't very pythonic. :/

Thanks :)